# Which volcano is the nearest to Santiago for kids friendly hiking

Tags: hiking, chile, volcanoes, santiago-de-chile

My search found this link on the [3 nearest volcanoes](http://southernpacificreview.com/2015/04/30/did-you-know-there-are-3-volcanoes-within-150km-of-santiago/). However, there are other volcanoes showing up in my seaches, *but* none of them have information on if they're open to the public/tourists and if they're kid friendly accessible?

**What is the nearest for *kid friendly* hiking accessible volcano to Santiago**?

---

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chile is a land of volcanoes, lakes and hot springs. The earth image you've included are part of the massive volcanic group that form the Andes.

Cajon del Maipo is the closest to Santiago, less than an hour away, and a very popular area with the locals. Within the canyon valley are the Volcán Marmolejo, Volcán San José, and Volcán Maipo.

[Lonely Planet](https://www.lonelyplanet.com/chile/cajon-del-maipo) offers excellent guidance, and has great options for your adventures with youngsters (and middlesters and oldsters).

> Rich greenery lines the steep, rocky walls of this stunning gorge of the Río Maipo. Starting only 25km southeast of Santiago, it's popular on weekends with Santiaguinos, who come here to camp, hike, climb, cycle, raft and ski.

You can get there by bus from Santiago, according to the seasons: as far as San Gabriel in the winter, by late spring and through the summer months, they reach Los Valdes. They depart every 30 minutes from Estacion La Florida.

In Santiago, Tourist Information offices are in Casa Colorada at Merced 860 and at Cerro Santa Lucia in Terraza Neptuno.

The official web site of the [Chilean Tourism Promotion Corporation](https://www.sernatur.cl/) has a wealth of information to help you plan.

Comment: This is a very nice answer, thanks! our trip is planned as a last min effort, so we want to cover what we can thats possible within a week near/around santiago

Comment: do you recommend 1) `renting a car` or, 2) `is there plenty of local transport?` or 3) `just going & staying there @ Rio Maipo for a couple of days?`

Comment: @transformer I think that would depend on the age of your children but, having a car in that area with an overnight or two, might be a great adventure, letting you experience the immensity of Chile, and the ability to reach key areas (monument, thermals, waterways) in the brief time you have.